# Is there anyway to implement a frosted glass floating div over HTML content (IO7-like)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All the ways of making a overlying `div` with frosted glass effect, usually can only do this based on an image background (such as http://www.blurjs.com/).

What I want to do is have a floating `div` (`position:fixed`) which will implement a frosted glass effect over whatever content is underneath, be it an image, text, video, etc..

Is this at all possible using any combination of jQuery/JavaScript/HTML/CSS ?

The only solution I've found so far is this one:

http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript

Problem with this one is that its very slow as it waits for the page to render first before doing its magic so wont really work well on a high traffic site.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089927/how-to-create-a-frosted-glass-effect-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  It seems this cannot be done in a dynamic way at this time.  There are promising changes to chrome to allow this in the future, but its all in developer stage at this time.

For now it can only be faked on static content.

Answer (score 1):

I took the link that @elliopizzaman gave, and enhanced the fiddle somewhat.  By adding a div layer that brightened the image, I could achieve a frosty-glass look.  The edges aren't what you might hope for, but the effect is OK.

http://jsfiddle.net/mNgQs/35/

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="frost"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#frost {
   position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.4);    
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;

    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);

    -webkit-filter  : blur(8px);
    -moz-filter : blur(8px);
    -ms-filter  : blur(8px);
    -o-filter   : blur(8px);
    filter      : blur(8px);
}
```

I don't know if the filter would be applied to something "behind" the div, if you e.g. made a "draggable" dialog -- for that you might have to do canvas work.

Comment: This is just blurring a preset image, bbut this does not work for trying to place a floating div on top of mixed text, image, video content

Comment: I think, for that you have to do some canvas work to capture the image behind the div and manipulate it.  And good luck doing that real-time, especially on a video.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want????? check the 
http://jsfiddle.net/mNgQs/36/
Changed the following to div

```
 -webkit-filter : blur(2px);
-moz-filter : blur(2px);
-ms-filter  : blur(2px);
-o-filter   : blur(2px);
filter      : blur(2px);
```