# Applying blur to multiple elements under a single div? Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, blur

I need something that would achieve this effect:

[image]

The closest I have found is the [blur.js](http://blurjs.com/) plugin but it only applies the blur to a single div's background image.

I want to have a div with a fixed positioning, with a z-index on top of a bunch of other divs and images and maybe even text. 
When you scroll, they move underneath it while it stands motionless and acts like a piece of frosted glass on top of them.

Am I fantasizing beyond what is possible? :)

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089927/how-to-create-a-frosted-glass-effect-using-css

Comment: Hm, thanks but it doesn't really. 
Css3's blur function blurs the contents of the div, not what is underneath it.
Answer 2 - suggests using a pre-made image. That's not suitable when the content needs to scroll under the blurred rectangle.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [`backdrop-filter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31628219/65387). Only Safari supports it.

Answer (score 0):

for blur effect underneath what you need is using `rgba background-color` with `backdrop-filter`:

```
background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.3);
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

and for make div fixed and be on all div you need `position` and `z-index`:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
```

support for all browsers

full code here:

> [github blur effect project](https://github.com/AsadiAhmad/Blur-Effect)

also you can see this blur effect for scrolling in these websites :

[Apple website](https://apple.com)

[znucomputer website](https://znucomputer.ir)

[a div with blur underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHJqO.jpg)

you can do this with only HTML and css:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url(./colory.avif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

div.text-conteiner {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

p.text {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
}

div.blur-glass {
    height: 300px;
    width: 70%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.3);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="text-conteiner">
        <p class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quod iusto explicabo earum impedit labore facere sunt? Non consectetur exercitationem cumque, eligendi dolores quos id! Eaque iusto beatae quidem! Illum atque officia, sed eos quo aperiam sit deserunt nesciunt adipisci ex laborum voluptatem, officiis doloribus qui optio odit. Illo non facere voluptas quasi debitis numquam cum voluptate commodi iusto nesciunt incidunt ea deserunt alias, cupiditate veritatis voluptatibus dolorum a qui nobis, eligendi molestias excepturi enim aut? Rem enim dolorem quasi sapiente illum illo fugit temporibus suscipit magni! Voluptate est, placeat ullam minus quas aspernatur eius nihil quibusdam temporibus accusantium. Officia atque autem saepe veniam consequatur cum magnam laborum. Eius sequi facilis quas consequatur, dolores maxime, assumenda illo, adipisci aut voluptatum dolorum saepe minus esse hic modi nemo earum corrupti recusandae repellat. Praesentium iure dolorem reiciendis earum deserunt eius tenetur culpa cupiditate officia asperiores suscipit sed quibusdam perspiciatis minima accusantium, nesciunt quaerat </p>
        <p class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quod iusto explicabo earum impedit labore facere sunt? Non consectetur exercitationem cumque, eligendi dolores quos id! Eaque iusto beatae quidem! Illum atque officia, sed eos quo aperiam sit deserunt nesciunt adipisci ex laborum voluptatem, officiis doloribus qui optio odit. Illo non facere voluptas quasi debitis numquam cum voluptate commodi iusto nesciunt incidunt ea deserunt alias, cupiditate veritatis voluptatibus dolorum a qui nobis, eligendi molestias excepturi enim aut? Rem enim dolorem quasi sapiente illum illo fugit temporibus suscipit magni! Voluptate est, placeat ullam minus quas aspernatur eius nihil quibusdam temporibus accusantium. Officia atque autem saepe veniam consequatur cum magnam laborum. Eius sequi facilis quas consequatur, dolores maxime, assumenda illo, adipisci aut voluptatum dolorum saepe minus esse hic modi nemo earum corrupti recusandae repellat. Praesentium iure dolorem reiciendis earum deserunt eius tenetur culpa cupiditate officia asperiores suscipit sed quibusdam perspiciatis minima accusantium, nesciunt quaerat </p>
        <p class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quod iusto explicabo earum impedit labore facere sunt? Non consectetur exercitationem cumque, eligendi dolores quos id! Eaque iusto beatae quidem! Illum atque officia, sed eos quo aperiam sit deserunt nesciunt adipisci ex laborum voluptatem, officiis doloribus qui optio odit. Illo non facere voluptas quasi debitis numquam cum voluptate commodi iusto nesciunt incidunt ea deserunt alias, cupiditate veritatis voluptatibus dolorum a qui nobis, eligendi molestias excepturi enim aut? Rem enim dolorem quasi sapiente illum illo fugit temporibus suscipit magni! Voluptate est, placeat ullam minus quas aspernatur eius nihil quibusdam temporibus accusantium. Officia atque autem saepe veniam consequatur cum magnam laborum. Eius sequi facilis quas consequatur, dolores maxime, assumenda illo, adipisci aut voluptatum dolorum saepe minus esse hic modi nemo earum corrupti recusandae repellat. Praesentium iure dolorem reiciendis earum deserunt eius tenetur culpa cupiditate officia asperiores suscipit sed quibusdam perspiciatis minima accusantium, nesciunt quaerat </p>
    </div>
    <div class="blur-glass"></div>
</body>
```