# Cross-browser frosted glass effect with css

Tags: html, css, svg, masking

i'm trying to create an frosted glass effect for logo on my site. Logo is moving with parralax effect over the div with background image and blurs background. So i decided to use one focus image and one blurry which will be showing through the .svg mask.

[frosted glass effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckqcR.jpg)

I created the demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZEn7/3/) which works perfectly but only on webkit browsers.

Is it any chance to recreate that effect whith Firefox or IE? Thanks!

**Update**

If i place html and svg on the same domain mask is working in Ferefox, but how to change size and position of mask?

**html**

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="stuff">Other stuff</div>
```

**css**

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
.intro {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/KsfKCre.jpg) center no-repeat;
  /* Image Credit: Unsplash.me */
  background-size: cover;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/x4DIKBs.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(../img/radio-checked.svg);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position-x: 50%;
  -webkit-mask-position-y: 50%;
  -webkit-mask-size: 350px;

  mask: url(../img/radio-checked.svg#mymask);
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;

  /*seems doesn't work in Firefox*/
  mask-position-x: 50%;
  mask-position-y: 50%;
  mask-size: 350px;
}
.stuff{
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

**svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by IcoMoon.io -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<mask id="mymask">
<path d="M100 0c-55.229 0-100 44.771-100 100s44.771 100 100 100 100-44.771 100-100-44.771-100-100-100zM100 175c-41.421 0-75-33.579-75-75s33.579-75 75-75c41.421 0 75 33.579 75 75s-33.579 75-75 75zM62.5 100c0-20.711 16.789-37.5 37.5-37.5s37.5 16.789 37.5 37.5c0 20.711-16.789 37.5-37.5 37.5s-37.5-16.789-37.5-37.5z" fill="#ffffff"></path>
</mask>
<path d="M100 0c-55.229 0-100 44.771-100 100s44.771 100 100 100 100-44.771 100-100-44.771-100-100-100zM100 175c-41.421 0-75-33.579-75-75s33.579-75 75-75c41.421 0 75 33.579 75 75s-33.579 75-75 75zM62.5 100c0-20.711 16.789-37.5 37.5-37.5s37.5 16.789 37.5 37.5c0 20.711-16.789 37.5-37.5 37.5s-37.5-16.789-37.5-37.5z" fill="#000000"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: The easiest and by far most supported method would be to use something like Photoshop to [create a PNG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9dRfCtDriI) with the desired shape. While this type of thing *may* be possible in the browsers of the future, cross browser right now it's just not going to happen very easily

Comment: The mask and main html document must have the same domain which is why the jsfiddle does not currently work.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! I place svg and html on the same domain and mask have started to work in Firefox, but i have [no luck](http://i.imgur.com/z0CzOlB.jpg) trying to change its size or position.

Comment: SVG mask elements have x and y attributes. Try modifying those.

Comment: I have tried something like `<mask x="0.03" y="0.12" id="mymask">`, but it only [crop](http://i.imgur.com/6yC5MQ7.jpg) mask, not moving it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a frosted glass effect using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089927/how-to-create-a-frosted-glass-effect-using-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the 'frosted glass' effect implementable with CSS only at this time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528880/is-the-frosted-glass-effect-implementable-with-css-only-at-this-time)

Answer (score 0):

According to caniuse, you need to inline your mask SVG if you want it to work in FF.  Try that.

http://caniuse.com/css-masks

Comment: I don't think that's true. The svg mask and the html document must have the same domain though which the jsfiddle does not.