# Is the 'frosted glass' effect implementable with CSS only at this time?

Tags: css, svg-filters

The frosted glass effect (where an overlay both blurs and tints what is below it) is a common UI element in iOS.

Is there currently anyway to implement that with CSS? There are a lot of questions pertaining to this, but they are limited in what they can do. They typically are limited to putting an overlay over an image--rather than a completely rendered UI.

So, to be clear, I'm not looking for a way to blur an image by itself, but a way to blur the UI below an element. So say I have an HTML form with HTML buttons and HTML text, and I want to place a div above them all so that whatever is below looks blurred. And then I can perhaps scroll what is below and as elements come in and out of the overlay, they are blurred only while under the div.

My understanding is that the answer to this is **no, this is not currently possible with CSS** but I'm also a bit rusty on the new bells and whistles...

Comment: you can put an overlay on the entire body  `position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;`

Comment: It will be with [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter). You could construct work-arounds with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter), [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) and [`background-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode).

Comment: @maioman the overlay is simple. It's the frosted glass effect that is the challenge.

Comment: @Xufox yep, backdrop-filter is *exactly* what I was looking for. I guess I'll just wait 4 or 5 years and maybe a few browsers will support it. :) As for the workarounds--are you aware that any of them work as filters for "everything below"? Most examples I've seen apply them only to a single image.

Comment: Downvoter...please let me know how to improve the question.

Comment: you could fill the overlay elem with images and use opacity

Comment: @maioman I don't think you maybe understand the effect I'm after. It's where it appears you're looking through frosted glass...where elements that are behind it can be seen, but they are blurred and washed out. I don't want to apply the effect to an image, but rather to the DOM itself.

Comment: please make a fiddle /sketch

Comment: @maioman the typical example is how iOS does it with overlays: http://photos.appleinsider.com/ipad-130624-8.jpg

Comment: Like this http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/d056d1b26b9683c018f9bb9e0f1b0e1c ?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith no. That's one of the 'hacks' that's only blurring an individual image (and actually using two images). Note that if you place text top of the image, the overlay doesn't let that text show through.

Comment: you've already probably seen [this](https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/)

Comment: @maioman that's what adam linked too. Again, that's applying a blur to an image by itself--not a 'chunk of the DOM' as a whole.

Comment: it's not that hard with JS http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/BooEdd

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto that's neat but doesn't appear to be live updatable so I assume that's still a bit of a hack

Comment: if you go that way then all JS is a bit of a hack... but I get your point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is `backdrop-filter`, which has been in webkit since August 2015 ([see post](https://webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/)). It was shipped in Safari 9 ([September 30, 2015](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW22), part of OS X El Capitan) and works in Chrome today by enabling the **Experimental Web Platform features [...]** flag.

With backdrop-filter, getting the 'live blur' is as easy as adding `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)` to a given element.

Demo [here](https://codepen.io/danmindru/pen/vXJNgg).

It's probably going to be a while until it becomes mainstream though, but it's going to enable us to do so much more than the frosted glass effect (i.e. night mode, [read more here](https://fadeit.dk/blog/2016/09/27/backdrop-(filter)-it-like-its-hot/)).
The good news is that tons of people are excited about it, so let's hope we don't have to wait long. If curios, [here's](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filters-2/#BackdropFilterProperty) the spec for it.

If you want to track progress on this feature, check out:

- [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1178765)
- [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497522) & [Chrome status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5679432723333120)
- [Microsoft bug](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9160189-backdrop-filters)

Comment: I love having answer like this pop up a year later. This is pretty slick! Is this relatively new? (I've lost track of what versions of Safari were released when...)

Comment: @vals haha! +1 for having cats in your answer, missing some in mine.

Comment: @DA. updated the answer with the release date & some other goodies 

Comment: This is still very buggy and incomplete anywhere except Safari.

Comment: @MichaelMullany indeed. IMO it's only a matter of time before it lands in Chrome though, according to the activity on the bug I linked in the answer anyway (last commit a few hours ago)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is achievable only in Firefox.

The key is background-image: element. One of the properties that would prove most useful , in my opinion,  of the ones in the "may be some day" list

Demo working only in FF ..   Notice that frost is not a child or a parent of test

```css
img {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  animation: move 1s infinite;
}

#frost {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,100,0.2), rgba(0,0,100,0.2)), -moz-element(#test);
  background-position: -45px -112px;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  filter: blur(4px);
  opacity: 1;
}


button:hover {
  background-color: red;  
}
@keyframes move {
  from {transform: translate(0px);}  
    to {transform: translate(40px);}  
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <button>BUTTON</button>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/750" width="300px" height="300px"/>
</div>
<div id="frost"></div>
```

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks !

Comment: This is pretty slick! Alas, it's still not the ideal 'live' effect that I was looking for in that you can't have the DOM below actively updating and preserve a live blur. All that said, I think this is close as we can get for now. (alas, by the time the browsers fully support it, it'll be an out-of-style effect anyways :)

Comment: @DA. _“You can't have the DOM below actively updating and preserve a live blur”_ Works for me, though…

Comment: @Xufox In some case works, in others doesn't ...  See the edted smippet. The animation won't work, but the hover on the button will.