# Frosted glass effect using CSS for h2/h3 background area

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently styling an events site and for the index page - representing each event I have an image with the event title and event date sat on top of the image. I currently have these in h2/h3 brackets, plain white text with a solid color background. I want to change the background to a 'frosted glass' effect using CSS. How do I do this?

Here's my current view Rails/html code and CSS styling -

index.html.erb - events

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul>

                <% @events.each do |event| %>
            <li class="events"> 
                    <%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event, id: "image" %>
                <div class="text">  
                    <h2><%= link_to event.title, event %></h2>
                    <h3><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h3>
            </li>       
                <% end %>
                </div>

        </ul>                           
    </div>
</div>
```

events.css.scss -

```
li.events { 
width: 350px; 
height: 350px; 
float: left;
margin: 20px;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative; 

 }

 li.events img { 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
border-radius: 25px;



 }

div.text  { 

background: transparent; 
padding: 25px; 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 15px;
left: 25px; 

}

div.text a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;   
text-align: center;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #FF69B4;


     }
```

I imagine the image looking a bit like this (not the best screenshot - sorry).
[image: Frosted Glass background effect]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also an image of how this is **supposed to look** would be helpful. What you think of a *frosted glass* might be different from others. Like this - https://jsfiddle.net/yok43f3w/1/

Comment: You could try to transform your HTML to actual valid HTML and make it run in a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). That way it's easier for people to fix.

Comment: Apologies, I'm fairly new to SO. I wasn't sure whether there were different 'types' of this background - it's a design I see more and more - basically sat over an image allowing the text to stand out. Similar to what you see on Apple designs. So, I have to re-submit this question as a snippet?

Comment: Nothing is currently broken per se, the main part of the code which I want to transform is this -      

div.text a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 5px; 
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background-color: #FF69B4;}

Comment: Please provide an image or link of what you try to achieve. I don't know what you're talking about and googling for "apple frosted" ... well ...

Comment: I think I know what you try to accomplish. It's the glass look like the good old title-bars in Windows, where you can see through, but kind of blurred and faded. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks, I've posted an answer also. I do like that link and had seen it before. I like the idea of a pop up menu and may consider using that whilst I'm still in development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the 'frosted glass' effect implementable with CSS only at this time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528880/is-the-frosted-glass-effect-implementable-with-css-only-at-this-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just googled "frosted glass effect" and the second result looked promising: https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/. It links to codepen: http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/40cd4258f2d72a60f37a5e2f47124b7e

They use a blurred image for the blurry effect. Depending on the browsers you need to support you can use the CSS property `filter` instead. That way you only need to load the image you want to apply your effect to and not a second with the applied effect.
I made a fiddle for you: **https://jsfiddle.net/hwvpch0u/1/**

Basically it's mostly all about the following **CSS**:

```
.mycontainer {
    background-image: url('<my-image>');
    background-size: cover;
}
.mycontainer .glass {
    /* all the properties for the "stand out" container */
}
.mycontainer .glass::before {
    /*background-image: url('<my-blurry-image');*/ /* see: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter */
    background-image: url('<my-iamge>');
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px); /* blur only of original image is used instead of blurry */
    filter: blur(8px); /* blur only of original image is used instead of blurry */
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

---

In your additionally added screenshot, I cannot see a blur effect. So if you don't need that, you can just apply an background-color having an alpha channel to the "frosted" container above the image, like:

```
.mycontainer .glass {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the only part of this with which you need help is making your solid background color look like frosted glass. That is a somewhat subjective criteria, but based upon the image you've provided, all you really need to do is make the background color semi-transparent. The way to do that would be to get the rgb value of your color, and pass it like so:

```
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the responses - I've found a solution here -

```
div.text a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FF69b4;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 5px;   
text-align: center;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: invert(10px);


}
```

Comment: You do know that this is only supported in Safari and no other browser as of now, don't you? --- http://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working in development mode on chrome, though?

Comment: Sure, but how do you plan to publish your web-site? With an alert telling users to use Safari or activate developer-mode in their Chrome? --- I always assume someone does want wide browser support. If that isn't your goal, than you're good to go with draft-features like that.