# Hybrid menu background effect

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create this menu background effect in Ionic, but I have no idea what to use to recreate this.

[Link](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/121337/screenshots/2691834/menu_1x.gif)

At first I used opacity, but that doesn't give me the right effect. I added blur as well but no luck.

```
.menu-overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgb(43,49,81);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .8;
}
```

Edit: not talking about the animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a frosted glass effect using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089927/how-to-create-a-frosted-glass-effect-using-css)

Comment: See the proposed duplicate, I think that effect is what you're after.

Comment: Try my CSS filter playground here: http://brainlessdeveloper.com/definitive-guide-css-filter-wizardry/#section1 You can add your own image and try the blur effect combined with other filters.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have an image. The menu is an overlay, but I suppose that's not the way to go then?

Comment: @cybermonkey I did look there already but didn't manage to get things to work like I want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the solutions above, I have added a blur filter to the whole content where my menu hovers over.

In short:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content">
  <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu{
 opacity:0.9;
}
#content{
   filter: blur(4px); -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}
```