# Responsive frosted glass effect on card background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the background of this card to be frosted glass instead of white. From my google searches, this isn't something that's easy or straightforward to do. What's the best way I can make the card background a frosted glass effect so that the whole thing still stays responsive to vh and vw changes? I'm implementing this in ReactJS using the antd ui framework.

An idea I had was to make the background of this card invisible and then have another card as the background of this card which would have the filter: blur() css property but I can't get the sizing to work and I haven't figured out how to stack one card on top of another.

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
<div className="Login">
  <Row>
    <Col xs={{ span: 0 }} sm={{ span: 2 }} md={{ span: 6 }} lg={{ span: 8 }} xl={{ span: 9 }}></Col>
    <Col sm={{ span: 20 }} md={{ span: 12 }} lg={{ span: 8 }} xl={{ span: 6 }}>
      <Card
      title={<span className='title'><Avatar  size='large' shape='square' style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}/>title</span>}
      bordered={false}
      tabList={tabList}
      onTabChange={(key) => { this.onTabChange(key, 'key'); }}
      style={{ marginTop: '17vh' }}
      >
        {contentList[this.state.key]}  
      </Card>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={{ span: 2 }} md={{ span: 6 }} lg={{ span: 8 }} xl={{ span: 9 }}></Col>
  </Row>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show us image, what you want to do.

Comment: Have you considered using a :before pseudo element on the card? Similar to what you mentioned about having a transparent background, but instead of a bother ‘div’ create a before pseudo element with a height: 100% and a width of 100%. This will allow your “card” to control the height and width, with your frosted glass background filling the rest of the space.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887219/frosted-glass-look/48887665#48887665

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a CSS property called `background-clip`.

See demo on the link below and see how this small background is semi-transparent.

https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/0733d9cb92ca4213466922d2ebc775a7