# DIV with gradual blur effect around it

Tags: html, css

I need to make a gradual blur effect above a fixed div element which has '*backdrop-filter: blur(2px);*' so the content that's behind it gets gradually focused as it comes into full view.

Here's my current snippet of the page and the CSS im using:

CSS:

```
    #sum {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px 20px #0008;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
      background-color: #0008;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id='table'>
      <table id='days'>
        <tbody>
          <!-- a lot of table data -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id='sum'>
      <h2>TEXT 1</h2>
      <h2>TEXT 2<br>TEXT 2<br>TEXT 2</h2>
      <h2>TEXT 3<br>TEXT 3</h2>
    </div>
```

```css
#table {
  height: 70%;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 3vh;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#sum {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 0 15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 20px #0008;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background-color: #0008;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#sum h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id='table'>
  <table id='days'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id='sum'>
  <h2>TEXT 1</h2>
  <h2>TEXT 2<br>TEXT 2<br>TEXT 2</h2>
  <h2>TEXT 3<br>TEXT 3</h2>
</div>
```

...this results in a harsh *focused/blurred* line between *#table div* and the top of the *#sum div*.

I want the blur effect to be gradual, with no visible harsh line.

I asked uncle Google for help but I'm apparently asking wrog questions... I was close but i gave up... Only thing I've found is [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140378/using-a-shadow-together-with-backdrop-filter-blur) that mentioned exactly what I want to achieve but it was apparently a ?bug? that got fixed?

I **can** edit all HTML or CSS code, so any solution would be welcome.

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet that shows the problem? I ran the code you have given but it didn't show blurring.

Comment: @AHaworth not sure how to add it to the question but heres a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DMCroww/uxsew5yo/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you CSS Blur based on a gradient mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648881/can-you-css-blur-based-on-a-gradient-mask)

Comment: @Rojo Kinda... Stumbled across this when I was searching too... but this seems to blur the image itself so it would follow the table itself... I need to blur the table that is behind the #sum div , and have it come to focus once it scrolls from behind the div... would I somehow apply the code mentioned in that question to the #sum div itself? kinda at a loss on how I should implement that into my code.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about this here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2024/01/css-blurry-shimmer-effect/