# Frosted Glass effect: filter: blur()

Tags: html, css, filter, blur

**EDIT: added codepen links**

I'm currently attempting to get a frosted glass effect using CSS however everything I've tried has just resulted in a slight tint.

This is being tested in *Chrome*.

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/ht1etAo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.frost {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.frost:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(20px);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: -20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="frontImage">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="frost">
      <h3>Testing Glass</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

It doesn't actually seem like the filter property is working, as changing it doesn't actually effect the div.

Here's my code: I'm attempting to blur the frost div

Aiming for this kind of effect: https://codepen.io/AmJustSam/full/ModORY/

What I've got: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxWEde

I've attempted using webkit-blur too but that hasn't worked either.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. If further info is needed, please ask.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle/codepen or similar instead of a screenshot? Also I don't really understand what your desired outcome is, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Dont you want to apply the filter to the body (which has the background-image)?

Comment: Currently you're applying the filter to the before-element, which just blurs the box-shadow.  What exactly do you want to blur, the background image or the "Testing Glass"-element?

Comment: I'd like to blur the background behind the box

I've added codepens to show the desired result

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887219/frosted-glass-look/48887665#48887665

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/ht1etAo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.frost {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
}

.frost:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(2px);
  background: inherit;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  height: 140px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frost">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Testing Glass</h3>
    <p>lipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like the text to remain unfiltered, I explained what I wanted poorly.

I've linked a codepen to a coder (AmJustSam) who has an example of the kind of effect I'm looking to get

Comment: Can't you just copy the exact effect from the codepen? I've edited the above to better reflect the setup you need to match the linked effect.

Comment: I'm afraid not, when I tried it, it doesn't actually display anything

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way to get a realistic glass effect by using the blurred version of the original image.

Ps: Take it easy guys had an issue with HTML widget.

Here is the code hope that's help

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
text-align:center;
color:white;
}
.glass-effect--bg-inner {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
padding-top:20px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.large-hero--bg {
  background: url(https://cdn-std.dprcdn.net/files/acc_609131/p6BW2C) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 0;
}


.glass-effect {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;

}

.glass-effect--bg:after {
   
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url("https://cdn-std.dprcdn.net/files/acc_609131/EElxHZ") repeat fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 50% 0;
      content: "";
      filter: url("https://cdn-std.dprcdn.net/files/acc_609131/EElxHZ") repeat fixed;
      -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
      filter: blur(5px);
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="container large-hero--bg ">
  <div class="glass-effect glass-effect--bg">
<div class="glass-effect--bg-inner">

  <h2>Lorem ispsum dolor</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Thank you! This is more along the lines of what I want.

The only problem I'm having now is that it does not show the text and when the window is resized, it does not align with the window background.

EDIT:
Fixed text issue with z-index

Comment: You should be able to add whatever element you want into the glass-effect container. Let me know if that works.